# Can I Trip-Skip in GTA: SA iOS? If so, how do I activate it?

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I've had some frustration on the missions *'You've had your chips'* and *'Misappropriation'* because they have a very long driving section and I kept failing them and having to re-drive to the destination.

I've heard of this feature called 'Trip Skip', where you could skip directly to the destination and cut out the long drive. But there was no prompt or icon that says I could trip skip (or maybe I missed it).

Can someone tell me how I can do it, because the only mission I can trip skip now is '*End of the Line*'.

Comment: It was likely removed from the iOS version, although I cannot confirm this myself. The GTA:SA iOS version [was updated graphically & had some features removed](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Apple_iOS#Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas), with Trip Skip being such an [underused feature](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Trip_Skip) it might have also gotten cut.